# Unable to iterate over ManyToMany - how do I calculate the sum?

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

My models look like this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
description = models.TextField()
price = models.FloatField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s - %s" % (self.name, self.price)

class Order(models.Model):
client = models.ForeignKey(User)
articles = models.ManyToManyField(Article)
total = models.FloatField(editable=False, blank=True, default=0)

def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s - %s" % (self.client.username, self.total)

def save(self):
    for a in self.articles:
        self.total += a.price
    super(Order, self).save()
```

And I try to calculate the total price in save(). If I try to save an order via the admin, I get

> 'Order' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used

If I call

```
super(Order, self).save()
```

before calculating the sum, I get

> 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable
>   .

I don't know to do... I thought about calculating total in the view, but I would like to store it in my database.

How to I iterate over all the articles in the Order-Model?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd replace your total field with a property:

```
class Order():
    ....
    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.articles.aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum']
```

the reason is: when you add items to collection your object is not saved again, so it wouldn't update your counter. With this property you'll be sure to always have correct data.

Comment: doing this, django says: `KeyError: price_sum` in the `return`-line.

Comment: When your app gets tons of visitors that see this total, you should investigate ways to [cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/) this value or maybe whole view.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but I think there is no need to cache total - it's only used internally by a few hundred users max.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to do this, you could save the instance first if it has no PK:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.pk is None:
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    for a in self.articles.all():
        self.total += a.price
    super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: this gets me the mentioned "'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterabable" - I tried this version, too.

Comment: Replace `for a in self.articles` with `for a in self.articles.all()`. 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable indeed. :-)

Comment: oh, I forgot the `.all()`. Saving seems to work now, but `total` is not calculated.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman you said "If you really need to do this..." Is there a better way? I'm still learning django, so any hints are appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation. Replace

```
for a in self.articles:
    self.total += a.price
```

with

```
from django.db.models import Sum

#..............
self.total = self.articles.aggregate(Sum('price'))['price__sum']
```

Comment: your solution is working too - can't vote you up, because of rep. but thanks!